# Which would be the equivalent command for addValueEventListener in Swift 3

Tags: android, ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase and Swift 3 and I wanted to know how can I translate this from my Android app to Swift 3:

```
DatabaseReference signalReceivedReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("users/" + mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid() + "/signal_received");
      signalReceivedReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue()).equals("true")){
                    showToast(getString(R.string.signalReceived));
                    dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue("false");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

I tried this but it did't work:

```
ref.child("users").child(userID!).child("signal_received").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if(snapshot.value as! String == "true"){
                self.view.makeToast("Signal received")
                snapshot.ref.setValue("true")
            }
        }) { (error) in
        }
```

Comment: What didn't work about the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `addValueEventListener` which listens to changes, whereas in Swift you've used `observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: ...)` and this only observes the value once. You can use `observe(.value, with: ...)` to listen to changes.

```
ref.child("users/\(userID!)/signal_received").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if(snapshot.value as! String == "true"){
        self.view.makeToast("Signal received")
        snapshot.ref.setValue("true")
    }
}) { print($0) }
```